# How can I take live input from a form, and print it?

Tags: javascript

I have seen similar questions answered, but they are being printed to an input attribute as seen [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2crfB/)

```
<input type="text" id="field1">
<input type="text" id="field2">
<script>
document.getElementById("field1").onkeyup = function() {
document.getElementById("field2").value = this.value; 
}
</script>
```

but I want to print to text for a live demo of an email.

Comment: "For a live demo of an email"?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "demo of an email?" Do you want the input to be rendered into an email template, like a preview of how the final email will look before it's potentially sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are, just change the input for a span and ".value" for "innerHTML"

```
<input type="text" id="field1">
<span id="span"></span>
<script>
    document.getElementById("field1").onkeyup = function() {
        document.getElementById("span").innerHTML= this.value; 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set an event listener. 'change' is the event you'll want to listen for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

```
document.getElementById("field1").addEventListener('change', ({target: {value}}) => {
  document.getElementById("some-element").innerHTML = value; 
});
```

Comment: But he wants to copy the value to text, not to an input

Comment: @MatíasRodríguez I'm a little unclear on what that means. "copy" as in to the clipboard? Or make the text appear in a <div>?

Comment: The second option I think. What you do he already knows how to do (see the link that he shared)

Comment: @MatíasRodríguez this answer does exactly what your answer does - replicate the text from an input to a div/span.

Comment: My bad, that's true

Answer (score -1):

You can just show the text field contents in a div.

```
<input id="input" type="text"/>
<div id="output"></div>

<script>
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input").value;
</script>
```

Comment: @MatíasRodríguez Yep, that's true. From the code posted I assume OP already knows how to register a listener to run this code on whatever event he wants.